Were there clues for the astute reader in Eustace Pedler's diary entries?
I've just read Agatha Christie's The Man in the Brown Suit, which is freely/legally available to read online. The story is largely narrated by the main protagonist Anne Beddingfeld, with some chapters being excerpts from the diaries of Sir Eustace Pedler. Anne acknowledges the latter at the beginning:

Very fortunately, too, the gaps that I cannot supply from my own knowledge are amply covered by Sir Eustace Pedler’s diary, of which he has kindly begged me to make use.

At the end of the story, we discover that

 Eustace Pedler is in fact the mysterious "Colonel", the criminal mastermind behind all the schemes in the story.

A surface reading of his diary entries does not, of course, make this fact obvious. They describe, in what seems to be a genuine manner, events in the day-to-day life of Eustace Pedler, consistent with

 his public persona, without mentioning any of his secret activities as "the Colonel".

But are there hints which an astute reader might have picked up on, indicating that

 he is an unreliable narrator?


I don't have a book with me but I've read an analysis (that's why this is not an answer but a comment) that tells how you notice. Basically, there are minor discrepancies between Anne's point of view and Sir Eustace's. There are also certain "blind spots", or blackouts, where significant events happen in Anne's recollection but Sir Eustace for some reason doesn't deem significant to write about. Any reasonable person would write about them, but he for some reason doesn't. That reason is because he is guilty party, of course.

@jo1storm Sounds interesting! Where did you read that analysis? Do you think you'd be able to find it online with some searching? An answer that largely quotes someone else's well-reasoned analysis would be fine.

I'll try to find it. What I remember that this was one of the hints "It has been a delightful week. I have done everything I wanted to, and nothing that I did not want to do." Basically, every time Sir Eustace does what he wants to do and has time to do it, someone ends up either murdered or a different crime has been committed.

Another thing to look for is Sir Eustace having fun. Readers really don't want him "having fun". If I remember correctly, he also spends half of his diary complaining about being forced to work by different people (mostly his assistant Pagget). That's because when he is doing genuine work, he can't do work needed for his criminal enterprise. So he tries to get his freedom as much as possible. Meeting with his unnamed friends is another one.
